# Php error in curl function

Tags: php

i got this error while running php code

> Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\OTP\process.php
>   on line 25 Call Stack #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0030  151192  {main}( )   ..\process.php:0

how to resolve this

Comment: You could install cURL

Answer (score -1):

Try following steps:

Click wamp icon. and go to php -> php extension and check "PHP_CURL" is ticked or not.

If not checked then click it and restart wamp.

if you not understand in above then follow below instructions.

Go to your php.ini file and remove the ; mark from the beginning of the following line:

;extension=php_curl.dll

After you have saved the file you must restart your HTTP server software (e.g. Apache) before this can take effect.

"do not forgot to restart server"

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate and poor-researched questions . Thank you.